# Ender 3 Pro reads SD G-code file names but won't print them

Tags: creality-ender-3, g-code

I have updated my Ender 3 Pro to 4.2.7. The printer boots up, I can move X, Y, and Z-axis from the **Prepare** > **Axis** screens. The printer also correctly reads the G-code file names from an inserted SD card.

However, when it should be printing based on G-code commands, the printer just stops. Printing used to work with the same SD card and make prints.

I updated the firmware with:
`Ender-3 Pro_4.2.7_BLTouch_Marlin2.0.1_V1.1.2_TMC2225.bin`

I am stuck!! Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Always try a different SD card. Make sure that it is formatted as FAT32 (maximum size 32GB).